# How to set visibility of layout by using parameter from a function in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Trying to create a function with string para that manupulate visibility of layout

```
Vis("VISIBLE","GONE");
...
...
...
public void vis(String a, String b){
Linearlayout1.setVisibility(View.a);
Linearlayout2.setVisibility(View.b);
}
```

Is it possible? With any way.

Comment: are you looking for a method that can change the visibility of the views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are trying to do that when you can simply use this:

**`View.setVisibility(View.GONE / View.VISIBLE / View.INVISIBLE);`**

In your context it can be

```
Linearlayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And

```
Linearlayout2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

This is already provided functionality in android sdk. Please refer to developer docs for further detailed info on same.

Comment: Because when dealling with lot of layouts

Comment: You should not try to re invent the wheel these native sdk features are properly tuned for usage If you try to create your own then you will end up in a mess. What do you mean by **lot of layout** ? How many? I don't understand your purpose please give more details.

Comment: Working with 8 layouts.evry time methods are called it set them according to need. VISIBLE or GONE. So writing the same statement again and again is a real mess. So i wanted to impliment a function for that. With the same no. Of parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
Vis(View.VISIBLE,View.GONE);
...
...
...
public void vis(int a, int b){
Linearlayout1.setVisibility(a);
Linearlayout2.setVisibility(b);
}
```

not recommended, but will do the job.

Comment: Actually there are lot of layouts which needs to be switched from visible to gone .. so is there any better way to do this

Comment: If you can update the xml file, then I guess we can help. There might be chances where just changing the visibility of parent layout can help you